# How to perform SQL Query to get last entry

Tags: sql

I am working on creating a SQL query where the result will return a student test score 
from the last test that they took. I think that this should be fairly simple but I am just not seeing it.

Here is my test data

```
Name    Date        Score
John    2/3/2012    94
John    2/14/2012   82
John    2/28/2012   72
Mary    2/3/2012    80
Mary    2/28/2012   71
Ken     2/14/2012   68
Ken     2/14/2012   66
```

I want the returned result to be

```
John    2/28/2012   72
Mary    2/28/2012   80
Ken     2/14/2012   66
```

I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Look at the Aggregate function Max() and  group by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select date, name, score
from temp t1
where date = (select max(date) from temp where t1.name = temp.name)
```

OR

```
SELECT a.*
FROM temp a
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT name,MAX(date) as max_date 
  FROM temp a
  GROUP BY name
)b ON (b.name = a.name AND a.date=b.max_date)
```

Here is a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7294/3) with an example

or even this if you have more than one record for each person on a date like you show in your sample data.

```
SELECT c.name,c.date, MAX(c.score) as max_score
FROM
(
 SELECT a.* 
 FROM temp a
 INNER JOIN 
 (
  SELECT name,MAX(date) as max_date 
  FROM temp a
  GROUP BY name
 )b ON (b.name = a.name AND a.date=b.max_date)
)c
group by c.name,c.date
```

[Sql fiddle with this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7294/7)

Comment: Bluefeet - Thank you. That's is it. Thanks as well for the SQL Fiddle site. I have not seen this one previously. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, Date, Score
FROM tablename t1
WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) 
              FROM tablename
              WHERE Name = t1.Name
              GROUP BY Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Which database are you using?  Most support `row_number()` which is the right way to answer this:

```
select *
from 
(
  select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) as seqnum
  from table t
)
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: I plan on using MS SQL. Interesting concept using Row_numbers(). I will have to check this out more. Thank you.